# Which of the following relations are partially ordered relations and which are linearly ordered relations.

Tags: relations

I was given the following task to do

> Which of the following relations are partially ordered relations and
> which are linearly ordered relations.
>
> $ (x, y) \preceq_1 (x', y') $ if both $x \le x'$ and $y \le y'$ are
> true.
> $ (x, y) \preceq_2 (x', y') $ if either $x \le x'$ and $y \le y'$ is
> true.

Could you please explain how do we solve such a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first relation is a partial order but not total, since $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ are not comparable.

The second relation is not a partial order, since $(1,2)\prec_2(2,1)$ and $(2,1)\prec_2(1,2)$, but $(1,2)\ne (2,1)$. Antisymmetry fails.

Comment: What is (x, y). Set, ordered pair, or just an arbitrary object ?

Comment: Its an ordered pair.